# Angular Material design is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to add angular material design in my website.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

But its not working for me.Please help me...

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? We don't know how to help if we don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer in the following order.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css"> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 </script>
```

Working [`App`](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SMgJS?p=preview)